# How to get @variabe_name from getelementptr inbounds instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I read the documentation but not sure how to fetch this value. I was able to read direct getelementptr instructions.
Code:

```
 struct foo {
 unsigned char position;
};

extern struct foo f1;

void hello () {
  if (f1.position){
  }
}
```

IR code:

```
%struct.foo = type { i8 }

@f1 = external dso_local global %struct.foo, align 1
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable mustprogress
define dso_local void @_hello() #0 !dbg !9 {
  %1 = load i8, i8* getelementptr inbounds (%struct.foo, %struct.foo* @f1, i32 0, i32 0), align 1, !dbg !13
  %2 = icmp ne i8 %1, 0, !dbg !15
  br i1 %2, label %3, label %4, !dbg !16

3:                                               
  br label %4, !dbg !17

4:                                          
  ret void, !dbg !19
}
```

I would like to fetch f1 from getelementptr inbounds instruction.

Many Thanks.

Comment: If you have a [GetElementPtrInst](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html) or  [constant GEP expression](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html#a32947e091cb9ab02766ea84e58c6d996), you can call getOperand(0)->getName() to get the name of its first operand.

Comment: @arnt
 `Instruction * Inst = load i8, i8* getelementptr inbounds (%struct.foo, %struct.foo* f1, i32 0, i32 0)`
`Value *V=Inst->getOperand()[0] `
`*V = i8* getelementptr inbounds (%struct.foo, %struct.foo* f1, i32 0, i32 0)`
**V->getName() // does not return anything (expected f1)**

Comment: The "f1" that you see when you print the IR is the output of a getName() call. I suspect that you're calling getName() on the wrong objct. FWIW isa<GlobalVariable>() returns true for the object that has name "f1", and you can call print() or dump() on any object to get the IR representation. I hope this helps.